# Do I need a bidirectional logic shifter for UART

Tags: logic-level

I need to interface my Raspberry Pi to my Uno hence I need to logic shift 5 V logic to 3.3 V. I will be sending data from the Uno to Pi and from the Pi to the Uno.
My understanding is UART uses two pins one for sending and one for receiving. I have built myself one of these

[image]

I have only built myself one of these because I wasn't confident I can build it. I was expecting it would blow up or won't work.
Anyway I was wondering do I need two of the above. Can I get anyway with just two of the following?

[image]

It would be very handy if I can because then I don't have to use more transistors and it's my understanding the first circuit is essentially the second circuit doubled up.

Comment: Please edit the question and use the built-in schematic editor. No need for copy-pasting CircuitLab images. CircuitLab is built into the question & answer editor. Just click on the schematic icon above the editor markdown input area when editing the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*The following is a rough-and-ready technique for experiments, and if you check all the voltages carefully, might be suitable for some designs.*

One of the simplest methods, suitable for UARTs and short distances, is simply divide down the higher volts with a resistor divider. In this particular case, there's not any real noise margin, but for an experiment on the bench you can try this.

You have to check the exact details of the given systems

- **UNO Input**: With a ATMega328P at 5V (such as in your Arduino Uno), the 3.3V signal is adequate as a high signal, where a the high threshold is 0.6 V<sub>CC</sub>, ie 3.0 V.  The minimum promised logic high voltage, V<sub>OH</sub> min, on some models Raspberry is also 3.0V ([ref](https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/raspberry-pi.html#gpio)), so it will work on the bench but you'd probably not want to do this in production.  On some models it's only 2.4V, which may well not be enough to drive the ATMega.
- **Raspberry Pi Input** In the other direction, you should check on your exact model in the [Raspberry Pi datasheets](https://datasheets.raspberrypi.com/), but on a 3.3V system you have assume that V<sub>IH</sub> max is no higher than V<sub>CC</sub>, ie 3.3V.  For the [RPi4](https://datasheets.raspberrypi.com/rpi4/raspberry-pi-4-datasheet.pdf) these values are unhelpfully given "TBD", though say "VDD_IO is the GPIO bank voltage which is tied to the on-board 3.3V supply."  This appears to be the same as the CM4, where there is a voltage reference for GPIO, V<sub>GPIO_VREF</sub>, which can be 1.8V or 3.3V. On the CM4IO board, it's 3.3V, giving V<sub>IL</sub> min is 2.0V and max is V<sub>GPIO_VREF</sub>, ie V<sub>CC</sub>, ie 3.3V.  See table 4 of [CM4 datasheet](https://datasheets.raspberrypi.com/cm4/cm4-datasheet.pdf), V<sub>GPIO_VREF</sub> is set by R5 on Fig. 5, of [CM4IO datasheet](https://datasheets.raspberrypi.com/cm4io/cm4io-datasheet.pdf).  Some more values are given in the [overview documentation](https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/raspberry-pi.html#gpio).

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fCteFu.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Calculating the resistors:
5 V * 33000 / (18000 + 33000) = 3.24V

### ATMega328P

Note that the reset and crystal pins have different thresholds.

[image]
*From [ATMega328P datasheet](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/Atmel-7810-Automotive-Microcontrollers-ATmega328P_Datasheet.pdf)*

Comment: How do you know if 3.3V is adequate on a 5V system? On some systems it might be. Especially in this case it isn't, as a 5V ATMega328P requires at least 0.7*VCC so 3.5V at 5V supply to read high. It goes the other way too; some 3.3V MCUs tolerate 5V but not  Raspberry Pi.

Comment: @justme Are you sure?  I checked datasheet (and added a reference to this answer), I see no 0.7 x Vcc except for the crystal.  The later ATMega328P*B* has an 0.7 x Vcc for Vcc<2.4V and 0.6 x Vcc above; but the UNO of the question is a 5V 328P.  If I've missed something I'll happily correct my answer.

Comment: You also need to check the `Voh(min)` for the 3.3V system. This will likely be lower than 3.3V, and if it ends up being lower than `Vih` for the 5V system allowing some noise margin, not a good design choice.

Comment: There are specifications for the RasPI IO pins listed [here](https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/raspberry-pi.html#gpio), part way down there is a table for "Voltage Specifications". That lists `Voh` can be as low as 3V for RPi2/RPi3 and 2.6V for RPi 4, which would be at (no noise margin) or below the `Vih` for the 5V atmega. Might work fine for a one-off, but I wouldn't trust it for anything important or in quantity.

Comment: @TomCarpenter thanks very much for better ref, I've edited the answer to say it's a rough-and-ready one for the bench.

Answer (score 0):

> Can I get anyway with just two of the following?

Note that the two sub-circuits in the first figure are different. You need one for 3-to-5V translation, another for 5-to-3V.

Since both the 3V and 5V output are driven all the time, there's no need for pull-ups. So only then do the two circuits become identical:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fkuoly.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: I got the circuit from a different thread on here.  It said the first circuit is bi-directional version of the second, is that not true? By bidirectional I assumed it meant 3.3V to 5V and 5v to 3.3V

Comment: R1 probably not needed  unless the inout signal is also driving a pulldown load

Comment: @Ageis: With UART, which has two opposing unidirectional signals, you **really** do not want a bidirectional level translator.  Those have a nasty habit of detecting some noise at their output and starting to drive the input.  Instead, use a unidirectional translator appropriate to each signal direction.

Comment: Oh is that why I got random values when reading from the serial interface